# FosFacebookConnect Popup disappears immediately

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, fosfacebookbundle

i use Fos Facebook Bundle v 1 in symfony 2.1 but it works at 90%.
Some browers (but it's work usually with all browers), opens a login popup but close it immediately, where the problem may come ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem, what is happening is that

1) You are logged into facebook,

2) You already authorized the application.

You can check it by login into facebook page and navigating to `Settings -> Applications` (https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications), there you will be able to see all the applications you are supposed to use, including your own application.

So, when you are loged into facebook and you already gave authorization to some app, the JS SDK will close the login popup inmediately giving the app the corresponding permissions.
Try deletting the app from your setting and login again into the app, this time the popup will be shown.

Hope this help you.